# How do I use an image to fill a layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to draw a map, and I'd like to fill the polygon that describes a country with a photo from that country. I know I can pass a CanvasPattern to `ol.style.Fill`'s `color`, but I don't know to generate an image.

Here's my code, and a JSfiddle with a full example: http://jsfiddle.net/07366L44/5/

```
function getPhoto() {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var photo = new Image();
  photo.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/C6PL9tB.jpg';

  return context.createPattern(photo, 'repeat');
}
```

I think it's because the photo is loaded async. Other examples create the pattern in the `photo.onload` method but I don't know how to return that.

Optimally I'd like to return a canvas which I can animate or update later with other photos, but I'll settle for just a single static image per country!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set your style's fill color in the image's `onload` handler.

```js
/**
 * @param {ol.style.Style} style Style to set the pattern on.
 */
function setPattern(style) {
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var photo = new Image();
  photo.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = photo.width;
    canvas.height = photo.height;
    var pattern = context.createPattern(photo, 'repeat');
    style.getFill().setColor(pattern);
  }
  photo.src = 'http://i.imgur.com/C6PL9tB.jpg';
}
```

Note that the fill's color needs to be set before the style function is called, so you cannot call the `setPattern` function in the style function. It's better to create the style before loading the layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how to set the style after I've generated the map, though, can you help?

Comment: To answer that, you'd have to provide more context, i.e. where you're currently using your code (style function? somewhere else?), and how (set style on layer, or on feature?)

Comment: I have this jsfiddle linked in the original post: http://jsfiddle.net/07366L44/5/ (thanks for your help btw)

Comment: Here is your fiddle, updated to work with the code from my answer: http://jsfiddle.net/07366L44/8/

Comment: Thank you so much! It makes a lot of sense seeing it like this. I really appreciate the help!