# Applying an image as fill pattern to a polygon does not change its style

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, openlayers

I'm trying to apply an image as a fill pattern to my polygon, but the polygon style does not change, it keeps the default one (if none has declared initially). I tried to change this by loading directly in the VectorLayer's style option and then tried to load as a separate style function. I tried to apply a predefined style, but then this one does not change too. In all cases I can see that the image does not even load in Developer Tool's Network tab. I don't know what I'm doing wrong since I'm following some successful cases ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36840884/7123439), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50175978/7123439) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46109065/7123439)) and I'm not receiving any errors.

- **OL version:** 6.1.1
- **Using Ionic Framework**

**My latest try: (EDITED)**

```js
let mainVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource ({
        format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'}),
        url: 'assets/geojson/randomArea.geojson' 
    }),
    name: 'mainVector'
});
let cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
let ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
let img = new Image();
img.onload = () => {
    let pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, 'repeat');
    mainVectorLayer.setStyle(
        new Style({
            fill: new Fill({
                color: pattern
            })
        })
    );
};
img.src = 'assets/images/pattern1.png';
```

**As a style function**:

```js
let mainVectorLayer = new VectorLayer({
    source: new VectorSource ({
        format: new GeoJSON({dataProjection: 'EPSG:31982'}),
        url: 'assets/geojson/randomArea.geojson' 
    }),
    name: 'mainVector'
    style:() => {
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = 'assets/images/pattern1.png';               
        let ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext("2d");
        image.onload = () => {
            let pattern = ctx.createPattern(image,"repeat");
            return new Style({
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: pattern
                })
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/nt6ae1Ld/), Jonatas Walker was able to load the pattern image for a feature. I believe that the same method can be used in for a VectorLayer since both have `setStyle()` method.

Comment: The first method should work but you should specify the onload function before setting src as setting src will cause onload event to fire.https://jsfiddle.net/0nduht34/  Your second method won't work as the synchronous style function will complete before the asynchronous load (and the style function must return the style, not the onload function)..

Comment: Thank you very much, very informative, I didn't realize that setting the `src` would trigger the `onload()` event. Changing the position solved the problem! I was also using the wrong path to my image, which made me lose some more hair, but everything is okay now. You can write an answer if you wish and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I'm also very interested in how to can make the second method work, so then I can apply in a more complex function involving multi polygons that return multiple styles for each one. I'm trying different ways to accomplish this, now using Promises, but every time I receive a "style.getImage is not a function" error. If you think you need more information I can open a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Mike's suggestions and the [continuation of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59274588/how-to-apply-a-pattern-fill-style-to-a-multipolygon-that-returns-multiple-styles/), the problem can be solved using a function like displayed bellow, which apply the desired pattern to a `VectorLayer`.

```js
stylePatternSimplePoly(pattern:string, vectorLayer) {
    let ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    let vectorImage = new Image();  
    vectorImage.onload = () => {
        console.log("Function triggered!");
        let createdPattern = ctx.createPattern(vectorImage, 'repeat');
        vectorLayer.setStyle(
            new Style({
                fill: new Fill({
                    color: createdPattern
                })
            })
        );
    };      
    vectorImage.src = 'assets/images/patterns/' + pattern;  
}
```